# Background and Foreground colors in terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code

For the last 2 versions of VSCode, the terminal colors are almost unreadable.  When I run angular serve, ionic serve the background is light blue with white foreground.  I don't know who can read that, but I can't.

I don't see any setting to set the terminal screen colors, can this be changed?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the terminal colors, see [workbench theme colors](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/theme-color-reference).  Perhaps your settings got changed somehow.  For terminal colors, try:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {

    "terminal.background": "#000",
    "terminal.foreground": "#fff"
}
```